# Why cant I insert values into 2D vector when I try to do it in a function in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11, multidimensional-array, stl, stdvector

I am creating a small C++ program for homework. I im trying to populate a 2D vector but when I write matriz[iA][iB]=iNum; it gives me the error "no match for 'operator='"

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <math.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <iomanip>
#include <set>
#include <vector>
#include <map>



using namespace std;

void popularMatriz(int iTamano, vector<vector<int>> *matriz){

    for(int iA=0; iA<iTamano; iA++){
        for(int iB=0; iB>iTamano; iB++){
            int iNum;
            scanf("%d", &iNum );
            matriz[iA][iB]=iNum;
        }
    }
}

int main(){

    int iTamano;

    scanf("%d", &iTamano);

    vector<vector<int>> matriz(iTamano, vector<int>(iTamano));
    matriz[2][2]=5;

    popularMatriz(iTamano, &matriz);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Change `matriz` to a reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing a pointer to `matriz`; so is wrong use it as

```
matriz[iA][iB]=iNum;
```

I suggest you to pass it as reference; I mean, define `popularMatriz()` as

```
void popularMatriz(int iTamano, vector<vector<int>> & matriz)
```

and call it without `&`

```
popularMatriz(iTamano, matriz);
```

Comment: I tried that and when I do it it compiles but when I run it the function doesnt run. It skips it. What can I do?

Comment: @EduardoDeLaGarza Fire up your [development environment's debugger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debugger) and step through the function. You will probably be embarrassed at the typo when you see it.

Comment: @EduardoDeLaGarza - I suppose it's the line `for(int iB=0; iB>iTamano; iB++)`; try changing `iB > iTamano` with `iB < iTamano` (as pointed by grigor)

Comment: @EduardoDeLaGarza - en passant: `matriz[2][2]=5;` is very very dangerous if you're not sure that `iTamano > 2`

Comment: When I read it I literally started laughing! Thank you very much! Somehow my debugger didnt enter the function so I just saw it skipping it. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

You're taking a pointer to `matriz`. Do this instead:

```
(*matriz)[iA][iB]=iNum;
```

Comment: thanks. I tried that but when I do it and run it it ignores the function and skips it. What can I do?

Comment: You have a mistake in `for(int iB=0; iB>iTamano; iB++)`. Should be `iB<iTamano`